# Is it possible to make JavaScript work in Sidebar of a Firefox WebExtension?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions, firefox-sidebar

I was trying to build an extension for Firefox and was going through [Mozilla's tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/user_interface/Sidebars), but got stuck pretty quick and now I need some clarifications.

So, I was thinking about adding a Sidebar, which will contain a lots of buttons (like, it will be an emoji picker, there each button would add an emoji to a specific field, when the user press it) and other things.

manifest.json:

```js
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Test extension",
  "description": "Just a test extension.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_specific_settings": {
    "gecko": {
      "strict_min_version": "54.0a1"
    }
  },

  "sidebar_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/star.png",
    "default_title" : "Test sidebar",
    "default_panel": "ui/sidebar.html"
  },

  "permissions": ["storage", "tabs"],

  "commands": {
    "_execute_sidebar_action": {
      "suggested_key": {
        "default": "Ctrl+Shift+Y"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

sidebar.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="panel.css"/>
        <title>Test sidebar</title>
        <script src="panel.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" id="textField"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="addText()" value="Add Text"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

panel.js:

```js
function addText() {
    document.getElementById("textField").value += "Text";
}
```

[image: A siderbar]

But, it turned out that for some reason JavaScript in my sidebar doesn't work (I click on a button, but nothing happens), while on sites like Codepen [it does](https://codepen.io/xplt/pen/ZEWjXZB) and I don't understand why: Is it limitation of an extension? Am I doing something wrong? So a hint of what's wrong would be appreciated. Thanks.